# Check and Uncheck the "check all" checkbox jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

[image]

On page load. I want to check the `check all` checkbox. If all checkboxes in a row are checked (add, edit, delete, view) and uncheck the `check all` checkbox if one of a checkbox in a row is unchecked (add, edit, delete, view).

Please see the image attached.

Here's my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_add[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_edit[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_delete[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_view[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="select_all[]"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_add[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_edit[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_delete[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_view[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="select_all[]"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_add[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_edit[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_delete[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_view[]"><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="select_all[]"><br>
```

Comment: You need to share your code, both html and the script that was tried

Comment: I think that code is not the original html....

Comment: it's just a sample :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/b80aogLk/47/)

HTML:

```
    <table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_add[]" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_edit[]" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_delete[]" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_view[]" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="select_all[]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_add[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_edit[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_delete[]" checked></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_view[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="select_all[]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_add[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_edit[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_delete[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="check_one" name="chk_view[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="select_all" name="select_all[]"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var rows = $("table tbody tr");
  $.each(rows, function(i,children) {
    var checked = $(children).find(".check_one").first().prop("checked");
    var total_checked = 1;
    $.each($(children).find(".check_one"),function(j,child){
        if($(child).prop("checked") != checked){
        total_checked = 0;
      }
    });
    if(total_checked == 1){
        $(children).find(".select_all").first().prop("checked",checked);
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I already have that function. My problem is when the page load. I want to auto check / uncheck the "select_all checkbox".

Comment: I've update a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/b80aogLk/47/

Comment: YeaH! you got it. Thanks a lot! :D